# Keep a Ruby project alive using Foreman

Tags: ruby, foreman

I have experience with Ruby on Rails but I'm trying to run [Stringer](https://github.com/swanson/stringer) the self-hosted RSS reader which is only Ruby. They suggest using Foreman to run the project which is fine, I can get the project up and running. However, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to keep the project running when I close the terminal.

I believe the Procfile is important in this process?? So here is mine.

```
web:     bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
console: bundle exec racksh
```

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm mostly an iOS developer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to daemonize the process, in which case just run:

```
foreman start &
```